# How to use across in an anonymous function in R

Tags: r, across

I had no problems in getting statistics from `df` tibble using this script:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  a = runif(5),
  b = runif(5)
)

funs <- lst(min, median, mean, max, sd)

sum_df1 <- map_dfr(funs,
  ~ summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), .x, na.rm = TRUE)),
  .id = "statistic"
)

sum_df1
```

But the way I used `across` is deprecated. So I tried the following without success:

```
# Due to deprecation
sum_df2 <- map_dfr(funs,
  ~ summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), \(x) na.rm = TRUE)),
  .id = "statistic"
)

# Error: only Booleans
sum_df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here col refers to the column and .x refers to the function:

```
sum_df2 <- map_dfr(funs,
  ~ summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), \(col) .x(col, na.rm = TRUE))),
  .id = "statistic"
)

identical(sum_df2, sum_df1)
## [1] TRUE
```

or we can do it the other way around where f is the function and .x is the column.

```
sum_df3 <- map_dfr(funs,
  \(f) summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), ~ f(.x, na.rm = TRUE))),
  .id = "statistic"
)

identical(sum_df3, sum_df1)
## [1] TRUE
```

or we could avoid using ~ entirely and use this where f is the function and col is the column

```
sum_df4 <- map_dfr(funs,
  \(f) summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), \(col) f(col, na.rm = TRUE))),
  .id = "statistic"
)

identical(sum_df4, sum_df1)
## [1] TRUE
```

As an aside `?map_dfr` indicates that it has been *superseded*.  That means it is not deprecated so it is ok to continue to use it but `bind_rows(map(...))` is preferred.  If we were to do that then we would redo `sum_df2` like this (and analogously for `sum_df3` and `sum_df4`):

```
sum_df5 <- map(funs,
     ~ summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), \(col) .x(col, na.rm = TRUE)))) |>
   bind_rows(.id = "statistic")

identical(sum_df5, sum_df1)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`purrr::partial`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/partial.html) to add/fill additional argument like `na.rm = TRUE`, e.g.

```
sum_df1 <- map_dfr(funs,
                   ~ summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric), partial(.x, na.rm = TRUE))),
                   .id = "statistic"
)


    # A tibble: 5 × 3
  statistic     a      b
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 min       0.288 0.0456
2 median    0.788 0.528 
3 mean      0.662 0.495 
4 max       0.940 0.892 
5 sd        0.294 0.302
```